# Eigenvectors and invariant sub space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> a. find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
>
> b. find the invariant subspaces and the dimensions
>
> Of a 30 degrees rotation matrix by the Z-axis

So the matrix is:\begin{pmatrix}
cos(\frac{\pi}{6})& sin(\frac{\pi}{6})& 0 \\
-sin(\frac{\pi}{6})& cos(\frac{\pi}{6})& 0 \\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Which is:

\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}& \frac{1}{2}& 0 \\
-\frac{1}{2}& \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}& 0 \\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Finding the eigenvectors:

\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\lambda& \frac{1}{2}& 0 \\
-\frac{1}{2}& \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\lambda& 0 \\
0&0&-\lambda\\
\end{vmatrix}

$P(\lambda)=-\lambda(\lambda^2-\sqrt{3}-\lambda+1)$

So the for the eigenvector $\lambda=0$ the corresponding eigenvector is:
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0  \\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

for the eigenvector $\lambda=e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}}$ the corresponding eigenvector is:
$\begin{pmatrix}
-i \\
1  \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

for the eigenvector $\lambda=e^{\frac{-i\pi}{6}}$ the corresponding eigenvector is:
$\begin{pmatrix}
i \\
1  \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

How do I normalize the last to eigenvectors? how so I find $P$ and $P^{-1}$ and how can I find the invariant subspaces?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, it sounds like you want to find the change of basis matrix $P$ and its inverse $P^{-1}$.

Luckily you've done the majority of the work.

The change of basis matrix $P$ is the matrix obtained from putting the eigenvectors of $A$ into the columns of $P$
$$
P=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-i & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Note that the columns of $P$ are all mutually orthogonal. This implies that $PP^\top$ is a diagonal matrix and indeed
$$
PP^\top
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, to force our change of basis matrix to be an orthogonal matrix, we need to "normalize" its columns, as you observe. This is easily done by dividing each column by its length. In our case we have
\begin{align*}
\left\lVert
\langle 1,-i,0\rangle
\right\rVert &= \sqrt{2} &
\left\lVert
\langle 1,i,0\rangle
\right\rVert &= \sqrt{2} &
\left\lVert
\langle 0,0,1\rangle
\right\rVert &= 1 
\end{align*}
Do you see how to get an orthogonal basis from here?

Comment: Yes, I just do not understand where the invariant subspaces come in, and why in the answer there is something written about unitary matrix